# JSON has multiple Objects with the same name

Tags: java, json

I have a small function that makes an JSON Api request and returns a string to Postexecute:

```
public class fetch extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        URL search = urls[0];
        String results = null;
        try {
            results = getResponse(search);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Now I want to get some specific JSON Objects, but I have multiple of the same Objects:

```
[
    {
        "A1": {
            "about": {
                "IDs": [19]
            }, ,
            "value": 1
        },
        "A2": {
            "about": {
                "IDs": [19]
            },
            "value": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "A1": {
            "about": {
                "IDs": [20]
            }, ,
            "value": 3
        },
        "A2": {
            "about": {
                "IDs": [20]
            },
            "value": 4
        }
    }
]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `[...]` represents array. If you know which item from array you want to get then simply use index of that item, probably via something like `yourJsonArray.get(index)`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a set of map objects in an array there.

Take a look at it in this pretty JSON editor: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=78f6765cb52e5403d01a8feead392611

You'll access array element 0 or 1 first, then access the map object.

```
secondObject = myjsonarray.getJsonObject(1)
a2 = secondObject.getJsonObject("A2")
thisisfour = a2.getInt("value")
```

Or all strung together:

```
thisisfour = myjsonarray.getJsonObject(1).getJsonObject("A2").getInt("value")
```

Relevant javadoc references:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

Comment: While having reference links is always helpful `AsyncTask` suggests Android not JavaEE. Anyway +1 for general solution which should be similar in most environments.